# Bootstrap 3 adds a right margin (?) on mobile

Tags: android, html, ios, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to set up two columns using bootstrap and CSS to remove the padding. Sadly, it adds a right margin whether I open the page on iOS Safari or Android Chrome. Here is a screenshot from Safari: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AybvJ.jpg

I've tried fixing the issue for a few hours, and I simply don't get it; the width of the elements should take 100% of the page. I've reduced my HTML/CSS to the bare minimum;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Demo</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <style>
            #mobile-page-navigation{
                padding: 0;
            }

            #mobile-page-navigation > div {
                margin-top: 10px;
                padding-left: 0;
                padding-right: 0;
            }

            #mobile-page-navigation div div {
                width: 100%;
                background-color: red;
                height: 100px;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="mobile-page-navigation" class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-xs-8 first-mobile-page-navigation">
                <div></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 second-mobile-page-navigation">
                <div></div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-4 first-mobile-page-navigation">
                <div></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 second-mobile-page-navigation">
                <div></div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about adding your col-xs-8 and col-xs-4 inside a class="row".

```
<div id="mobile-page-navigation" class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-8 first-mobile-page-navigation">
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 second-mobile-page-navigation">
    <div></div>
  </div>
--------
--------
</div>
```

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work, it just makes the element even bigger, and the small margin is still there. Just thinking about doing away with Bootstrap.

Comment: then please try to check ur outer container or whatever you have,may be its taking the margin from there.

Answer (score 0):

I did away with Bootstrap entirely. I can't manage to make it work like I want after a day of trying.

Answer (score 0):

You used bootstap's grid uncorrect. Maybe here is your html structure:

```
<body>
<div class="container">  
    <div id="mobile-page-navigation">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-xs-8 first-mobile-page-navigation">
               <div></div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-xs-4 second-mobile-page-navigation">
               <div></div>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-xs-4 first-mobile-page-navigation">
               <div></div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-xs-8 second-mobile-page-navigation">
               <div></div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

and here is your css:

```
        #mobile-page-navigation > div {
            margin-top: 10px;
            padding-left: 0;
            padding-right: 0;
        }

        #mobile-page-navigation div div {
            width: 100%;
            background-color: red;
            height: 100px;
        }
```

Maybe I didn't understand, here is an example [Codepen](http://codepen.io/ostinred/pen/jPQBeP)